# Regex to match x numbers and 1 letter

Tags: regex

How can I match any amount of numbers and exactly 1 letter (the valid letters being d, m, y to signify date unit)

e.g. Valid

- 1d
- 30m
- 1232y

e.g. Invalid

- 1dd
- 30mm
- 1232yyy

I've tried a few things like `[1-9]\b[a-zA-Z]\b` and `[1-9][a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Is for example `1d` the whole string or are you matching it within a larger string like `"I'll see you in 1d"`? Also, would you want to match e.g. `000000m` or `007y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the letter should be at the end

```
\b\d+[dmy]\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wywHqg/1)

To not match only zeroes like `00m`

```
\b(?!0+[dmy]\b)\d+[dmy]\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xoZJcs/1)

**Note** that `[1-9]` will not match a zero so `30m` will not match in that case.

Comment: Thank you, the latter fits, but is it possible to exclude the digit 0 if there's no other digit? e.g. `0m` and `00m` are not valid, but `01m` or `10m` are valid

Comment: @swtto I have added another pattern that does not match only zeroes.

Comment: @swtto Ypu can also shorten it to `\b(?!0+\D)\d+[dmy]\b`.